# Какие библиотеки установлены в питоне по-умолчанию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки

Хочу очистить проект от лишних установленных библиотек. К сожалению, начал очистку тогда, когда еще не знал про возможность удаления библиотек вместе с зависимостями с помощью pip-autoremove. Так что теперь такая штука не работает и я наблюдаю у себя множество огрызков библиотек, которые мне вообще не нужны. Слышал что-то про файл requirements, но я его не создавал, так что по нему тоже не смогу сориентироваться. Список библиотек получаю через pip3 list.
На текущий момент реально использую следующие библиотеки:

```
import psycopg2
import tqdm
from clickhouse_driver import Client
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict
import gc
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import json
```

Comment: Если необходимо, могу предоставить список, получаемый через pip3 list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Встроенные модули

Список встроенных модлей из стандартной библиотеки Питона смотрите в докментации: [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).

Из перечисленных встроенными являются `collections, datetime, gc, json`. Остальные необходимо устанавливать отдельно, например, через пакетный менеджер Питона `pip`.

---

## Порядок импортов

Помимо этого, в соответствии [с официальными рекомендациями PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), порядок подключения библиотек следует использовать такой:

1. Стандартные библиотеки.
2. Используемые сторонние модули.
3. Локальные модули вашего приложения/библиотеки.

В некоторых источниках также советуют отделять несколько импортов из одного модуля, а импорты с общей приоритетностью сортировать в алфавитном порядке.

Например, вот так:

```py
# Стандартные модули
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime
import gc
import json

# Сторонние модули
from clickhouse_driver import Client
import psycopg2
import tqdm

# Отдельно несколько строк с Торнадо
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
```

---

## Виртуальное окружение с зависимостями

Если в проекте много кода с разными зависимостями, то для выявления используемых библиотек следует использовать виртуальное окружение, например, [модуль virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html). Виртуальное окружение позволяет инкапсулироваться от модулей, установленных в Питоне глобально, устанавливая библиотеки с нужными версиями в рамках конкретного проекта. По этой теме много статей как на английском, [так](https://python-scripts.com/virtualenv) [и на](https://codecamp.ru/blog/python-virtual-environments/) [русском](https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-17-virtual-envs/). При запуске проекта в виртуальном окружении Вы увидите ошибки о недостающих библиотеках, которые нужно установить в локальном окружении проекта.

Однако виртуальные окружения существуют для использования модулей на месте, они не сохраняются в системах контроля версий. Для этого используется файл `requirements.txt`, в котором описываются нужные библиотеки и опционально их версии. Для быстрого создания этого файла можно заморозить текущие библиотеки из локального pip'a, а при создании нового окружения можно будет их легко установить из этого файла. Подробнее читайте в документации: [PIP > User Guide > Requirements Files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

Comment: Насчет отделения согласен, просто слил все библиотеки из разных файлов подряд. А в документации посмотрел первые же две библиотеки из моего списка  attrs 19.3.0 и backcall 0.1.0 - пусто. Причем я гуглил их функционал и во-первых я все равно не понимаю зачем они нужны, а во вторых понадобится очень много времени, чтобы проверить все.

Comment: @Сергей добавил информацию и ссылки по теме виртуальных окружений и requirements.txt, это поможет решить любые проблемы `(:`

Comment: У меня и так этот проект находится в виртуальном окружении. Я хотел просто создать еще одно и посмотреть, какие там будут библиотеки, но я не помню как его создал в прошлый раз. Возможно, у меня это получилось случайно. Пересмотрел несколько гайдов, в большинстве случаев его создают с помощью терминала bash, который у меня вообще в vs code не появляется, только python debug console и powershell.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решил просто удалить все пакеты кроме pip. Далее протестировал работоспособность проекта и на сообщения об ошибках просто доустанавливал необходимые пакеты. Размер проекта сократился с 250МБ до 46МБ. Никаких проблем не возникло.